# Obtener la suma de estas dos variables para poder asignar los ceros necesarios entre ellas

Tags: c#

Necesito sumar las variables sfact y nfact para saber cuantos caracteres juntan y restarle 9 para poder asignar numeros cero entre ellas dejo el codigo.

```
string dIni = dtpIni.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string dFin = dtpFin.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
//bool sTpo = rbtSI.Checked = true;
string fmt = "00000000";
string sFac = txtFactura.Text;
if (txtFactura.Text != "") {
    int nFac = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replace(txtFactura.Text, @"[^\d]", ""));
    sFac = nFac.ToString();
    string sSerie = txtFactura.Text.Substring(0,txtFactura.Text.ToString().IndexOf(sFac));
    sFac = sSerie + nFac.ToString(fmt);
}
```

Comment: Saludos, ¿podrías tomarte el tiempo de copiar y pegar bien el código? Te ayudamos a darle un mejor formato. Revisa este par de enlaces: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla.

Comment: Hola. Por favor dar un ejemplo de valor de `txtFactura.Text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para sumar los caracteres a los string puedes hacerlo con la pripriedad **.Length**

```
string sFac = "ADF";
int nFac = 34;

string ObtenerNumeroFolio(string sFac, int nFac)
{
   int longitud = 9 - (sFac.Length + nFac.ToString().Length);
   return sFac.PadRight(longitud + sFac.Length, '0') + nFac.ToString();
}
```

Con este método me devuelve el resultado que tu estas pidiendo. Lo que hace es recibir una cadena y un entero (puedes cambiarlos por lo que vayas a enviar modificando los **.ToString()** convenientes para calcular la longitud y devolver lo que deaseas.
Con el método **PadRight()** rellenas un string hasta la cantidad que le pases por parámetro y en el segundo parámetro le puedes decir cual quieres que use para rellenarlo.

Espero haberte ayudado! 
Un saludo

Comment: Que tal Rosca.
Lo que deseo hacer es poder generar un numero de folio con 9 dígitos.

por ejemplo sumo la longitud de sFac y nFac digamos que da 5. 
entonces 9 del folio menos 5 de la suma = 4.

ese 4 deben ser 4 ceros en medio de sFac y nFac
ejemplo: sfac = ADF + <CEROS> + nfac = 34 y que me regrese un resultado como este FOLIO :ADF000034

y así para cualquier caso poder calcular y asignar los ceros necesarios.

espero poder darme a entender un poco mas.

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta con la aclaración que me has hecho. Espero haberlo entendido bien lo que estas queriendo hacer y resuelto tu problema. Si no es eso lo que buscas intenta aclararme un poco mejor con algún ejemplo ya que se ve todo mas fácil que imaginarse las cosas.